# How to paste chunk of images one after another memory-efficiently?

Tags: python-2.x, python-imaging-library

I'm processing several hundred images by cutting them automatically at certain height and pasting the chunks one after the other. I create a new `Image` instance with `new` with a taller size than the last time in order to make space for the new chunk. When the processioning is done, the final result is saved to a file.

My problem right now is that this approach is that consumes a lot of RAM and Swap, almost freezing my computer. Is there a way to achieve my objective without consuming a lot of RAM? so far, this is the code I have:

```
import SimpleCV as cv
import argparse
import PIL
from os.path import join, abspath

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=("Process many images and paste the chunks into a final image"))
# ...code removed for brevity...
argv = parser.parse_args()
rango_inicio = int(argv.rango.split(":")[0])
rango_fin = int(argv.rango.split(":")[1])

img = None

for pag in xrange(rango_inicio, rango_fin + 1):
    numero = format(pag, '0' + argv.relleno)
    pagina = join(
        argv.dir_entrada, argv.prefijo + numero + '.' + argv.extension)
    pagina = abspath(pagina)
    print(pagina)
    imagen = cv.Image(pagina)
    fs = sorted(imagen.findLines(), key=lambda f: f.width())[-1]
    if fs.width() >= 598:
        cropped = imagen.crop(0, fs.y, imagen.width, imagen.height)
        if not img:
            img = PIL.Image.new("RGB", (cropped.width, cropped.height))
            croppedraw = cropped.getPIL()
            img.paste(croppedraw, (0, 0))
        else:
            croppedraw = cropped.getPIL()
            imgtmp = img.copy()
            img = PIL.Image.new(
                "RGB", (imgtmp.size[0], imgtmp.size[1] + cropped.height))
            img.paste(imgtmp, (0, 0))
            img.paste(croppedraw, (0, imgtmp.size[1]))

# and save the final image
```

Answer (score 0):

You are first loading the image in CV, then also making a list of each row in the image as a list, apparently only to find it's width, then you crop it, and then you make a PIL image out of it.

I think you can do all of this in PIL directly, which means you only need one copy of the file in memory, making this better.

That said, it shouldn't start to swap anyway, unless you have seriously huge images, as each image should be garbage collected once you have loaded a new image into memory, so there might be another issue involved.